# Sending URL params via EventMachine.connect

Tags: ruby, activemq-classic, eventmachine

Hi good people of StackOverflow.

I am having issues with `EventMachine.connect`, I am able to specify host name and port but not sent additional params in my connection string.

Here is my code:

```
EM.connect 'localhost', 61613, StompListener
```

Now I am experiencing issues with STOMP connection to `ActiveMQ` server, basically, connection keeps dying from time to time and I need to reconnect.  I have found following [info](http://activemq.apache.org/tcp-transport-reference.html) where Apache ActiveMQ suggests 
using `transport.keepAlive=true` for these cases. But I am not able to figure out how to add this URL params to `EM.connect`, do you know how?

Comment: It looks like EM.connect only establishes a connection to the server, which only compromises a domain and port. It's only a basic TCP connection, the same as if you had used a program like telnet to connect to a server. Additional information i.e., paths and query string parameters need to be sent over the connection after it has successfully connected. The Eventmachine docs demonstrate this with a simple HTTP GET request. http://www.rubydoc.info/github/eventmachine/eventmachine/EventMachine#connect-class_method

Comment: @maniacalrobot Thank you for info, I've tried it but it does not work since in `post_init` phase it sends action info (CONNECT) and it does not allow me to send params, I receive `unknown STOMP action`, still good tip - thanks man.

Comment: Does your `StompListener` mixing the `EM::P::Stomp` module? https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/blob/master/lib/em/protocols/stomp.rb has some examples with connection implementations. I'm afraid I'm not that familiar with the stomp protocol